# "Could not find a part of the path" C:\Users\username\abc\abc.exe.config

Tags: c#, filepath, streamreader

> configFilePath = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\abc\abc.exe.config";
>   if(File.Exists(configFilePath))
>   {
>   StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(configFilePath);
>   }

The above line throws "could not find part of the path" exception. This error occurs in a particular machine. In all other machines it works fine. And even in that machine , the same code worked before. No changes made in the machine. I have read all the forums where this issue had been discussed. But couldn't able to figure out why this happens in that machine alone and that too now. Having permissions to access the folder and file.

Comment: are you sure the file exists on that path ?

Comment: try `if(File.Exists(configFilePath))StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(configFilePath);` to make sure that file exists

Comment: The file exists and can able to edit the file manually. When I tried to access via c# code, throwing error.

Comment: have you tried configFilePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\", userName, @"\abc\abc.exe.config"); ?

Comment: The above code works in all the machines except one. So I am sure, the above code doesn't has any problem. If the way I have provided the path is wrong, it should not work anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) rather than string concatenation for paths. However, the user name may contain a character that is invalid in a path, such as a single quote, so it may have been escaped. Assuming "C:\Users" is the users' directory and not your own folder structure, a better solution is to lookup the user profile folder for that user using the [Environment.GetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) method with the `UserProfile` value from the [SpecialFolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: For your information, the username is Irodgers and it does not have any special characters.

Comment: You must use Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolders.UserProfile) for Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to think about is permissions on the file/folder. I've run into issues where all of a sudden the folder security gets out of whack because of a windows update.

Comment: from the question "Having permissions to access the folder and file."